# mergExt support for background tasks

Tags: iphone, livecode

I just bought the mergBgTask.
while using the demo file included with mergBgTask, I tried to run it in iPhone simulator but it didnt seem to make any difference pushing the With BG button or the Without BG, leaving the app and returning to it shows the counter at 1 and not counting anything.

I did copy the mergBgTask.lcext to its placein the standalone application settings.

Please advise.

Also, Does it support Livecode 6.0.1?

Regards,

Shmulik

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions in the README and/or here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qrnVGJ7lFA